# ¿Qué hace else: m+=1 en la función?

Tags: python

He encontrado en una página web el siguiente código en Python, pero no entiendo muy bien una parte:

```
from sympy import factorial

def a(n):
    m=1
    while True:
        if factorial(m)%n==0: return m
        else: m+=1

print [a(n) for n in xrange(1, 101)]
```

El problema que tengo es que la línea:  `else : m+=1` no sé muy bien que hace.

Comment: Simplemente incrementa en uno el valor de la variable `m` cuando el factorial de `m` dividido entre `n` da un resto diferente de 0. Es exactamente lo mismo que `m = m + 1`. No se si tu duda es respecto a que hace en si la línea o es más sobre el algoritmo en sí.

Comment: @FJSevilla ¿Y por qué pone al principio `m=1   while True:`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu algoritmo  lo que hace es generar la secuencia conocida como números de Kempner (generados por la [función de Kempner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_function)), que no es otra cosa que dado el entero `n` encontrar el entero positivo más pequeño (`m`) cuyo factorial (`m!`) sea divisible por `n`.

El algoritmo que muestras es el siguiente (vamos a verlo línea a línea):

```
m = 1
while True:
    if factorial(m) % n == 0:
        return m
    else:
        m += 1
```

- **`m = 1`**: la idea es buscar el primer entero positivo cuyo factorial es divisible entre 8 (`m! % n = 0`) debemos siempre empezar por el factorial del primer entero positivo, es decir 1. Por eso lo primero que se hace es asignar a `m` el valor de 1.
- **`while True`**: como a priori no sabemos cual es el valor de `m` que cumple la condición `m! % n == 0` usamos un ciclo `while` infinito. Esto se puede hacer de otra forma como veremos después.
- **`if factorial(m) % n == 0:`** esto es el núcleo del algoritmo, comprobamos si el factorial de `m` (para lo que se usa la función `factorial` que provee la biblioteca `sympy` en este caso) es divisible entre `n`.
- **`return m`**: si el `if` se cumple (`m!` es divisible entre `n` ) retornamos `m`. Esto ocasiona que la función termine, retorne el valor de `m` en ese momento y que el ciclo infinito se rompa.
- **`else: m += 1`**: si el `if` no se cumple (el resto de dividir `m!` entre `n` no es 0) se ejecuta el código contenido en el `else`. Si `m` no es el entero positivo que buscamos debemos incrementar su valor en 1 (`m += 1`, ver al final de la respuesta). Esto lo repetiremos hasta que encontremos un `m` que cumpla `m! % n == 0`, lo cual causa que la función retorne en el `if`.

Por ejemplo, para `n = 8` la secuencia es la siguiente:

> m = 1
>   m! = 1
>   1 % 8 = 1
>   m = m + 1
>
> ---
>
> m = 2
>   m! = 2
>   2 % 8 = 1
>   m = m + 1
>
> ---
>
> m = 3
>   m! = 6
>   6 % 8 = 1
>   m = m + 1
>
> ---
>
> m = 4
>   m! = 24
>   **24 % 8 = 0**
>   retornamos 4 (primer entero positivo que cumple m! % 8 == 0)

---

La función puede ser reescrita para evitar dos comparaciones por ciclo moviendo el `if` a la condición de control del `while`:

```
def kempner_num(n):
    m = 1
    while factorial(m) % n:
        m += 1
    return m
```

No deja de ser pura fuerza bruta, dada la complejidad del cálculo del factorial. Para ciertos valores de `n` puede ser interesante buscar una aproximación diferente usando las propiedades que tiene la función de Kempner, teniendo en cuenta que:

- `n!` es divisible entre `n` lógicamente. Entonces se cumple que `2 <= s(n) <= n`.
- Si `n` divide `m!`, entonces `n` también divide a todos los factores después de `m`.

---

**Anexo:**

`m += 1` es equivalente a  `m = m + 1` en este caso. Este tipo de sintaxis es conocida como *augmented assignment statements* y no es más que la combinación, en una sola declaración, de un operador y una instrucción de asignación. En Python existen las siguientes combinaciones:

> ```
> ┏━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
> ┃Expresión ┃  Similar*  ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ i += j   ┃ i = i + j  ┃   
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ i -= j   ┃ i = i - j  ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ i *= j   ┃ i = i * j  ┃ 
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ i @= j   ┃ i = i @ j  ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ i /= j   ┃ i = i / j  ┃ 
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ i //= j  ┃ i = i // j ┃ 
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ i %= j   ┃ i = i % j  ┃ 
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ i **= j  ┃ i = i ** j ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ i >>= j  ┃ i = i >> j ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ i <<= j  ┃ i = i << j ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ i &= j   ┃ i = i & j  ┃
> ┣━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
> ┃ i |= j   ┃ i = i | j  ┃
> ┗━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
> ```

*No se trata de expresiones equivalentes, `i = i + j` concatena `j` a `i` **creando siempre un nuevo objeto** resultado de concatenar `j` e `i` y reasigna a `i` la referencia al nuevo objeto. `i += j`  en cambio hace lo siguiente:

- Intenta hacer la concatenación/suma in-place (similar a `i = operator.iadd(i, j)`), si el **objeto es mutable** (`list`, `dict`, `set`, ...) realiza la **operación in-place** sin crear un nuevo objeto.
- Si **no es mutable** (`int`, `float`, `tuple`, `str`, ...) **crea un nuevo objeto**,  actúa como `i = i + j` (similar a `i = operator.add(i, j)`).

Mejor verlo con un par de ejemplos:

- Objeto inmutable (`int`, `float`, `tuple`, `str`, etc):

  ```
  >>> i = 5
  >>> id(i)
  1972745408
  >>> i = i + 3
  >>> i
  8
  >>> id(i)
  1972745504
  ```

  La id es única para cada objeto, simplemente es un reflejo de la dirección de memoria de ese objeto. Como podemos ver el nombre `i` ahora hace referencia a otro objeto. Esto implica que se crea una nueva instancia de `int` para almacenar `i + 3` y luego se le asigna a `i`. Esto también implica que el antiguo objeto al que hacía referencia `i` será destruido por el GC cuando haga una pasada y detecte que carece de referencias asociadas. En este caso, al ser `int` inmutable con `+=` nos pasa lo mismo:

  ```
  >>> i = 5
  >>> id(i)
  1972745408
  >>> i += 3
  >>> i
  8
  >>> id(i)
  1972745504
  ```
- Objeto mutable (`list`, `set`, `dict`, etc):

  ```
  >>> i = [1]
  >>> id(i)
  2379153761544
  >>> i = i + [3]
  >>> i
  [1, 3]
  >>> id(i)
  2379153265672
  ```

  Como vemos se repite el comportamiento esperado, se hace la operación `i + [5]` lo que resulta en una nueva instancia de `list` y este objeto se reasigna a `i`. En cambio con `+=` pasa algo diferente:

  ```
  >>> i = [1]
  >>> id(i)
  2379148377608
  >>> i += [3]
  >>> i
  [1, 3]
  >>> id(i)
  2379148377608
  ```

  El objeto es exactamente el mismo, en este caso simplemente se concatenado la lista `[5]` a la lista `i` in-place, tal como hace `list.extend`.  Una diferencia con este último es que hay una reasignación a la variable `i` en el caso del operador porque `+=` implica siempre el retorna un objeto (lo cual es congruente con el caso de aplicarlo a  objetos inmutables), en este caso se le reasigna la misma referencia al objeto `list` que tenía antes de la operación, ya que ésta se hace in-place.

La diferencia no es trivial para objetos mutables como cabe esperar:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit


>>> def foo():
...     a = []
...     b = [1]
...     for _ in range(1000):
...         a = a + b
... 
>>> timeit(foo, number=10000)                 
19.045519875000537


>>> def foo():
...     a = []
...     b = [1]
...     for _ in range(1000):
...         a += b
... 
>>> timeit(foo, number=10000)
0.4562984600015625


>>> def foo():
...     a = []
...     b = [1]
...     for _ in range(1000):
...         a.extend(b)
... 
>>> timeit(foo, number=10000)
0.7102556160007225
```

Crear un nuevo objeto cada vez, junto a la sobrecarga del recolector de basura al tener que liberar recursos del antiguo, tienen sus consecuencias... La diferencia con `list.extend` habría que investigarla a fondo, no obstante sospecho que se debe a la sobrecarga de `LOAD_METHOD` y `CALL_METHOD`.

Answer (score 0):

Si a lo que te refieres es que es exactamente m+=1, eso es lo mismo que decir 
m = m + 1; es decir, el valor de m es igual al valor de m + 1