# problema en condicion while "operadores de asignacion"

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Hola buenas tengo un problema que no entiendo al usar operadores de asignacion

el ejercicio se trata de imprimir una suma desde el 50+48+46+44...20

```
n=50 
h=0 #que hace esta variable?

while n<=20:
  h+=n #no entiendo lo que hace esto
  n -=2
print(h)
```

Salida

```
Aqui tendria que salir la suma de todos los numeros desde el 50 al 20
```

Comment: el print tiene que ir indentado

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué hace else: m+=1 en la función?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143229/qu%c3%a9-hace-else-m-1-en-la-funci%c3%b3n/143237#143237).  En cuanto al código ese `while` ni siquiera llega a iniciar, el condicional debe ser `while n>=20`... si quieres la suma de los pares entre 50 y 20 puedes hacer `print(sum(range(20, 51, 2)))`. `h` en tu código no es más que la variable que acumula la suma de los números, dónde `n` es cada número par generado al ir restando 2 al número anterior partiendo  desde 50  en cada iteración.

Comment: ¿No debería ser `n>=20`? La variable `h` es lo que se llama un "acumulador" que va aumentando su valor a medida que le sumas cosas. La línea `h+=n` equivale a `h=h+n`.

Comment: si he cometido el error es n>=20:

Comment: Para aclarar  `h += n` equivale en la práctica  a `h = h + n` en este caso, pero no siempre es así, depende de la mutabilidad del objeto. En mi respuesta a la  pregunta que dejo arriba se explica esto. Toma el valor  de `h`, le suma el valor de `n` y reasigna el resultado de nuevo a `h`. Es decir si tienes `h = 5` y haces `h += 2`, ahora `h` vale `7`.  Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> h=0 #que hace esta variable?

La variable "h" es un acumulador, es decir, se encarga de guardar la suma de cada valor de "n" mientras se ejecuta el bucle ***while***

> h+=n #no entiendo lo que hace esto

Eso es una abreviatura de la operación siguiente:

```
h = h + n
```

Es decir una abreviatura que indica que guarde el valor de "n" en "h" lo "acumule" mientras se ejecute el bucle ***while***.

> el ejercicio se trata de imprimir una suma desde el 50+48+46+44...20

Esto quiere decir que buscas es sumar aquellos números pares para los cuales existe la operación `n%2` que significa divide "n" sucesivamente por 2 hasta su mínima expresión (entera). Sabemos que un número par es aquel cuyo residuo final es 0 por lo que podemos utilizar el siguiente condicional en Python:

```
if(n%2==0):
```

Este condicional se leería: si el residuo de "n" es 0 (es par) entonces ejecuta la operación interna del if.

Debo comentarte que tu código tiene un error ya que si tomas en cuenta aquellos números para cuando "n" está entre 20 y 50 entonces la condición del ***while*** debe ser: `n>=20`, como "n" comienza en 50 sólo hay que chequear que se detenga el proceso cuando llegue a 20 (incluyendo el 20 tal cual como pediste).

Tomando en cuenta todo lo mencionado anteriormente tendrías el nuevo código que hace justamente lo que necesitas:

```
n=50 
h=0 

while n>=20:
    if(n%2==0):
        h+=n
    n-=2
print(h)
```

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!