# ¿Cómo hacer la forma más eficiente de contar las ocurrencias de elementos en una lista y generar una advertencia cuando no hay suficiente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimización

Estoy tratando de hacer la forma más eficiente de analizar una lista de etiquetas, contar las ocurrencias de elementos y generar una advertencia cuando no hay suficientes ejemplos de una `label` específica.

```
    import logging

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    if len(set(labels)) < 2:
        logger.warn("Can not train an intent classifier. "
                    "Need at least 2 different classes. "
                    "Skipping training of intent classifier.")
    else:
        lack_examples = []
        occurences = [[x,labels.count(x)] for x in set(labels)]
        for occurence in occurences:
            if occurence[1]<=2:
                lack_examples+=occurence[0]
            if lack_examples is not []:
                logger.warn("You should add more examples to", lack_examples)
        y = self.transform_labels_str2num(labels)
        X = np.stack([example.get("text_features")
                      for example in training_data.intent_examples])
```

Sin embargo, no muestra nada en la terminal con la siguiente lista `labels`:

```
labels = ['greet', 'goodbye', 'inform', 'greet', 'greet', 'greet', 'greet', 'greet', 'greet', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'goodbye', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'inform', 'laughing', 'laughing']
```

Sin embargo, solo hay dos ejemplos de `laughing`.

Estoy intentando contribuir con [rasa_nlu](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu), una herramienta para entender lo que se dice en breves fragmentos de texto.

#### actualizacion

Lo siento, solo lo pensé, pero luego utiliso `cv_splits = self._num_cv_splits(y)` los datos de entrenamiento se dividen en varias partes. Entonces el codigo:

```
import collections

occurences = collections.Counter(labels)

# El resultado es un diccionario cuyas claves son las palabras
# y cuyos valores son el número de repeticiones

if len(occurences) < 2:
    logger.warn("Can not train an intent classifier. "
                "Need at least 2 different classes. "
                "Skipping training of intent classifier.")
else:
    lack_examples = [label for label,count in occurences.items()
                     if count<=2]
    if lack_examples:
       logger.warn("You should add more examples to", lack_examples)
```

no funcionará, ya que no cubre todos los casos, ¿verdad? Durante la crossevaluation, sklearn emitirá esta advertencia cada vez que una de las partes no tenga suficientes muestras de entrenamiento. Por lo tanto, incluso si tiene 3 ejemplos, podría recibir la advertencia si tuvo mala suerte y todos estos ejemplos terminaron en una porción de los datos y ninguno en los demás.

Comment: ¿Qué es `logger` y porqué debería sacar algo en la terminal?

Comment: Si quieres contar las ocurrencias en un iterable, por lo general [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) es la mejor opción con diferencia. `

Comment: @ChemaCortes Creo que eso es lo que usan para comenzar las advertencias. ¿Debo usar el paquete `warnings`?

Comment: @Marine1 cuando se usa Logger el objetivo es guardar la informacion de las incidencias del programa en un archivo, y por ello probablemente no observas nada en la terminal, si tu no has colocado el Logger deberia estar documentado su uso en la libreria.

Comment: @eyllanesc ha, ok. Ya había visto en mi terminal el mensaje `Can not train an intent classifier...` así que pensé que funcionaría

Comment: @Marine1 te recomiendo que antes de contribuir en algo conocer al menos para que sirve el codigo que ya esta hecho sino vas a estar complicandote por gusto a cada rato, y las librerias de python casi siempre estan bien documentadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comentarios sobre tu código:

```
 lack_examples+=occurence[0]
```

<s>Para añadir elementos a una lista lo más eficiente es `lack_examples.append(occurence[0])`, ya que esto usa la misma lista que ya existía en `lack_examples` y le añade un elemento, mientras que el operador `+=` crea una nueva lista, resultado de concatenar la original más otro elemento, y asigna esa nueva lista a la misma variable. Tienes la sobrecarga (de CPU y memoria) de crear continuamente nuevas listas (aunque todas vayan a la misma variable), y además el recolector de basura deberá trabajar más para ir eliminando las antiguas versiones de la lista que ya no están referenciadas.</s>

> **Edición**: Como [@FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/fjsevilla) señala en un comentario, mi explicación anterior sólo es cierta para tipos inmutables (como strings o tuplas). En el caso de listas `+=` produce una actualización "in-place" como la que produciría `.append()`. La diferencia importante aquí es que, aunque `occurence[0]` es una cadena, al añadirla a la lista se tratará como si fuera otra lista (de letras), por lo que el resultado de `lack_examples += 'laughing'` sería `['l', 'a', 'u', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g']`, en lugar de `['laughing']`. Por tanto la recomendación de usar `.append()` sigue siendo válida, pero por otra razón distinta de la que expliqué.

---

```
 if lack_examples is not []:
```

Cuidado! El operador `is` no es para comparar contenidos de variables, sino para detectar *identidad* de las referencias. Es decir, `a is b` te va a dar `True` sólo si las variables `a` y `b` se refieren al mismo objeto, y no si simplemente se refieren a dos objetos que resultan ser iguales.

En el caso de listas, con `l is []` no estás mirando si `l` es una lista vacía, sino explícitamente sí es *esa* lista vacía en particular, la que acaba de ser creada al poner `[]` como parte de esa expresión. Ya que cada vez que haces `[]` en un código se crea una lista vacía nueva, te va a dar `False`, como puedes comprobar aqui:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l is []
False
```

Para comprobar si es una lista vacía la comparación ha de ser `==`

```
>>> l = []
>>> l == []
True
```

En realidad, una lista se pude usar como parte de una expresión booleana, y Python le dará el valor `False` si está vacía, y `True` si no, por lo que podrías poner simplemente:

```
 if lack_examples:  # Equivale a "si lack_examples no está vacía"
```

Por otra parte, esa comprobación deberías hacerla al terminar el bucle `for occurence in occurences:`, y no en cada iteración del mismo.

---

Por último, la *list comprehension* en la que cuentas cuántas veces aparece cada palabra dentro de la lista puede ser sustituido por `collections.Counter()`, que será más eficiente.

Por tanto tu código puede simplificarse mucho y quedaría así:

```
import collections

occurences = collections.Counter(labels)

# El resultado es un diccionario cuyas claves son las palabras
# y cuyos valores son el número de repeticiones

if len(occurences) < 2:
    logger.warn("Can not train an intent classifier. "
                "Need at least 2 different classes. "
                "Skipping training of intent classifier.")
else:
    lack_examples = [label for label,count in occurences.items()
                     if count<=2]
    if lack_examples:
       logger.warn("You should add more examples to", lack_examples)
```

Comment: Una pequeña observación, no es totalmente cierto que `x += y` cree un nuevo objeto siempre, en el caso de objetos mutables realiza la operación in-place. Al final de esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/143237/15089) lo intento explicar. El problema real es que `lack_examples += 'laughing'` desemboca en
`['l', 'a', 'u', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g']` y lo que quiere es `['laughing']` , es decir `append` como señalas. Un saludo.

Comment: @FJSevilla Gracias por la corrección. Tienes razón, me lié con los strings que, al ser inmutables, sí se comportan como expliqué. Voy a incorporar tu comentario a mi respuesta.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta! Sin embargo, solo pensé en una cosa estúpida que puse en actualización.
Es mi culpa, debería haberlo pensado antes.

Comment: @Marine1 No importa, la respuesta sigue teniendo partes aprovechables para otros, como lo del error de `if lista is not []`, o el preferible uso de `append()` para extender listas.